# Sas : partition a data given a curved variable

Tags: sas, partitioning

I have a database with serveral variables, including one, *RIF*, that hase an *x^2* shape relative to another variable, *Y*.
[image]

I want to obtain two seperate databases, separated based on whether the observation is on the decreasing or the increasing part of the curve.

I thought I had something by using the *lag* function, but my code does not work.

```
proc sort data=have; by y; run;
data want;
    set have;
    do while (rif<=lag(rif));
        Part=1;
        end;
    if Part ne 1 then Part=2
run;
```

And the separating given Part, but it seems to create infintite loop.

Is there a mistake in my code / is there a better way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
    do x = -10 to 10 by 1;
        y = x**2;
        output;
    end;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    lag_y = lag(y);
    if _n_ = 1 then Part=.;
        else if y <= lag_y then Part=1;
        else Part=2;
    drop lag_y;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks but there are two problems. One is that I still get Part=1 in the second part if I have equal values on the right part, which should not be the case. The other one is that on my data I seem to have rounded problems, so that it does not work properly.

Comment: @AnthonyMartin could you please upload your data as an attachment? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can use a file sharing service like Dropbox or Google Drive and post the link